# OrientDB collision probability on UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX?

Tags: orientdb

My code assigns UUIDv4 IDs for various entities (e.g. user accounts) in my system. While UUIDv4 is pretty much considered guaranteed unique, I'd rather be 100%, and as such, I've created an index of type UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX in my OrientDB instance.

However, I realized that the hash generated by OrientDB might be of a smaller size than my UUIDv4 value (128 bits), and I might get collision errors although the IDs are actually different.

I am not very familiar with the underlying hash algorithm used in OrientDB, and I was wondering if anyone can point out if whether or not it will be a possibility for me to get false positive collisions on my UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: Are you bothered about perfomance or uniqueness constraints of index ?

Comment: In this case, I'd say I'm willing to sacrifice performance in favor of a valid uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unique hash index we use concept similar to HashMap concept, if hash codes of keys are the same we put data inside of list of values associated with given hash code.

Comment: So, for example, say I have ID strings "A" and "B", and for some reason they would both hash to "1", our index would look like this?

1 -> [A, B]

So inserting B would still be possible even though it hashes to 1?

Comment: Yes , index is unique by value not by hash code , the same as hash map